# Can I change gedit's background color without changing to another theme?

Tags: gedit, themes

I like ambiance but i find it a little too hard on the eyes to have to edit files on a pure white background, like gedit's.

Is there any way to modify my theme to make gedit's background color darker?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As wojox said, you can change Gedit's theme.

The gtksourceview page ([old page from Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20120418203215/http://live.gnome.org/GtkSourceView/StyleSchemes)) ([new page from Wiki Gnome](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GtkSourceView/StyleSchemes)) on the Gnome website has more information about gedit themes. (Gtksourceview is the name of the software component that displays text in gedit.)

### Modifying Existing Themes

To modify the built-in themes, copy them from `/usr/share/gtksourceview-2.0/styles/` to `~/.local/share/gtksourceview-2.0/styles/` and edit the text files.

### Finding New Themes

You can find several themes in [this git repository](https://github.com/mig/gedit-themes/). It looks like you can install them with:

```
sudo apt-get install git-core
git clone https://github.com/mig/gedit-themes.git ~/.gnome2/gedit/styles
```

<sub>(This will allow you to run `cd ~/.gnome2/gedit/styles ; git pull` to get updates to these themes.)</sub>

### Building Your Own

You can also try this [online theme generator](http://scribes.sourceforge.net/themegenerator.php). I found that on [this article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/02/help-ubuntu-11-04-by-making-an-ambiance-theme-for-gedit/) about creating gtksourceview themes.

Comment: Thank you , I'll try the git repo and the generator asap

Comment: +1. Informative + bonus mention of the theme generator. Thanks :D

Comment: for completition; here in fedora i found an additionally gedit-plugin package "gedit-plugin-colorschemer" which lets me edit a color scheme directly in gedit

Answer (score 12):

Here are a few steps to change the GEdit background color.

1. Click on Text editor in the right-top corner.

   [image: Reference Image]
2. Click on **Preferences**.
3. Select **Fonts & Colors**.
4. Make the right choice (Cobalt is my favorite).

**Note: You can use Customized Color Schemes also.**

Answer (score 11):

Open gedit and go to Edit > Preferences > Font&Color. You can change it there. You may need gedit-plugins installed.

Comment: how can i create a color scheme using colors of my choice; it has too few (and too ugly) choices there.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Gedit doesn't let you change its current colors and save them as a new theme. I don't know why, as it seems pretty basic... Maybe the developers wanted to keep it as small and simple as possible.

Using the online theme generator is quite easy, though:

1. Go to the [Scribes Theme Generator](http://scribes.sourceforge.net/themegenerator.php) and pick the colors you want. The on-screen example shows how your choices look.
2. Click the "Generate" button to save your theme as an .xml file.
3. In Gedit's Edit menu, click Preferences; then on the Font & Colors tab, click the Add button. A file window appears. Select your .xml file and click "Add Scheme". Your new colors are immediately applied.

Answer (score 1):

Open the document `classic.xml`:

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles/classic.xml
```

Then You put the following just.

```
<!-- Global Settings -->
<style name="text" foreground="#black" background="#white"/>
<style name="selection" foreground="#white" background="#black"/>
<style name="cursor" foreground="#black"/>
<style name="current-line" background="#grey"/>
<style name="line-numbers" foreground="#grey" background="#white"/>
<style name="draw-spaces" foreground="#grey"/>
```

Comment: One does not use `sudo` for graphical applications. This might mess up some file permissions in your home directory. Use `gksudo` instead. I edited your answer.

Comment: @ByteCommander I think gksudo is deprecated, I cannot use it.

Comment: True, things changed since 2015. You should be able to use `gedit admin:///usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles/classic.xml` now instead. Or edit in the terminal with `sudo nano /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles/classic.xml`

Comment: @SauravSingh use `sudo -H` instead of `gksudo`, ie `sudo -H gedit /path/to/root-owned-file`

Comment: The good thing with `gedit admin:///$PATH` is that it works on Wayland too.